# writing contents in a table in a webpage into excelsheet

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver

guys this is the code for which i need get the website address into an excel sheet... but am unable to do so. its now showing me any kind of errors but the output is also not printing. kindly help.

```
    @Test
  public void f() throws Exception {
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper-all']/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")).click();
      Thread.sleep(3000);
      driver.findElement(By.linkText("Uptime, %")).click();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      List<WebElement> table = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper-all']/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")).findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper-all']/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a/img"));
      List<WebElement> list = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper-all']/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")).findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper-all']/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]"));
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      System.out.println(list.size());
  }
  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() {
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("http://www.proxy4free.com/list/webproxy_uptime1.html");
  }
```

Comment: Your code does not create, open or write any excel sheet.

Comment: am sry... but it atleast should print the list in the console... its not even doing that... i tried putting

 workbook.write();
 workbook.close();

but it is of no use... please kindly look into it

Comment: did you debug? Does the test finish normally without printing anything to the console?

Comment: yeah i ran the program in debugging mode... once i added  workbook.write();        workbook.close(); the test fails and it says null pointer exception..

Comment: Are you sure, you are using the intended xpath? can you post some html code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

Try to change:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElement
```

to

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements
```

Comment: Ya i did put da intended xpath.. if m nt trying to write it in excel sheet it does print it on console... and the test is sucessful... but the exception only occurs when i try to write the printed data in excel...